# Can UIAlertController and UIAlertAction be added in Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertaction

I have a bar button item in `Main.storyboard`, and I add some actions when click on it, my code reviewer wants me to put the `UIAlertAction` in `Main.storyboard` instead of adding it in the code, I wonder is it proper? If yes are there any way to do this? I don't find the `UIAlertAction` object.

```
- (IBAction)openFileUIBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                   message:nil
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *pickFileButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Pick A File" 

    //......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot able to add `UIAlertController` and `UIAlertAction` in `Main.storyboard`.... Just try to add it through programmatically, like what you done above..